# how to add an array to item in the firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to add an array to item in the firebase database ??? ....

[image]

add like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        dataModel = new DataModel();
        dataModel.setDate(now);
        dataModel.setTime(currentTime);
        dataModel.setBus_station(getCompleteAddressString(lat1, lon1));
        dataModel.setLatitude(lat2);
        dataModel.setLongitude(lon2);
        dataModel.setComments(editText1.getText().toString());

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabase = database.getReference("Markers");
        mDatabase.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).setValue(dataModel);
    }
}).start();}
```

and what appears in the picture appears, and when I add it again, everything is updated and remains the same, but I need to add the second data, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add new value in your list, you used use:

```
.push().setValue(...)
```

Your code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    dataModel = new DataModel();
    dataModel.setDate(now);
    dataModel.setTime(currentTime);
    dataModel.setBus_station(getCompleteAddressString(lat1, lon1));
    dataModel.setLatitude(lat2);
    dataModel.setLongitude(lon2);
    dataModel.setComments(editText1.getText().toString());

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabase = database.getReference("Markers");
    mDatabase.post().setValue(dataModel);
}}).start();}
```

Because when you get child `.child(id)` and that id exist, your just was update a exist data.

Comment: but if you need to add a new array into your child you must use:
`mDatabase.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).post().setValue(dataModel)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need add new marker every time ,you have to create new id. 
Simply like this:

```
mDatabase = database.getReference("Markers");
String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();
mDatabase.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child(id).setValue(dataModel);
```